# Is a bad NFS mount preventing a clean boot?

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, nfs

I'm on ubuntu server and I basically ran into this problem here
https://serverfault.com/questions/56588/unmount-a-nfs-mount-where-the-nfs-server-has-disappeared

The `umount` command didn't work, so I tried to just use the ol' reboot. Now the machine gets an error when booting:

```
FS-Cache:netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
<two minutes later>
init: udevtrigger post-stop process (345) terminated with status 1
```

I tried booting in recovery mode so I could just comment out the bad NFS mount in my `/etc/fstab` file, but I wasn't able to write the changes.

I basically just want to get the machine booting properly again so that I can erase the bad mount point, either order is fine.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I got into recovery mode I ran `mount -o remount,rw /` so that I could save my changes and get rid of the NFS problem. I still had other boot issues, but this was the key to clearing up the one I mentioned in the question.